# sum the marks and rank them by number

Tags: sql

I have table students table with these fields

```
student  continent        marks
john      Asia             500
jack      south America    600
Amy       Africa           450
Olive     Africa           600
Jay       Africa           755
Mackey     Asia            699
James     Europe           823
```

I've tired to sum the marks by below code to print continent and total marks -

```
SELECT  continent, sum(marks) as Totalmarks 
from students 
group by continent 
order by Totalmarks desc;
```

What should I do to rank them and print in below desired output -

```
continent  Totalmarks  Rank
```

Comment: *below desired output* ???

Comment: I meant I need the out put as in mentioned format.

Comment: sorry, but what you gave us is not enough as a detail for the desired data set. You can elaborate like the table content you shared.

Comment: James and Jack may find `SUM()`  unfair. Why not use `AVG()` instead, if you want to compare student results.

Comment: I just need query to print output as 

Continent  |   Totalmarks  |  Rank

asia           |     2022         |   1
africa         |    1805          |   2
south america| 850          |    3

Comment: By the way, everybody implicitly asking for your DBMS implicitly by their answers.

Comment: I'm just trying to execute it online on www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_sql_online.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `DENSE_RANK` instead of `ROW_NUMBER()` in the query below if you want to assign the same rank to a tie

```
SELECT 
continent,
SUM(marks) AS Totalmarks,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(marks)) AS rank
FROM students
GROUP BY continent
ORDER BY Totalmarks DESC
```

Comment: thanks but I wanted to rank them by ROW_NUMBER. Got what I needed :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER`. Try like:

```
     SELECT continent
            ,sum(marks) AS Totalmarks
            ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                ORDER BY Totalmarks
                ) AS rank
        FROM students
        GROUP BY continent
        ORDER BY Totalmarks DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You use `rank()` or `dense_rank()` depending on how you want to handle ties.  With aggregation, this looks like:

```
SELECT continent, sum(marks) as Totalmarks,
       dense_rank() over (order by sum(marks) desc) as the_rank
from students 
group by continent 
order by Totalmarks desc;
```

I suspect you want `dense_rank()` so:

```
total   rank dense_rank
 100      1      1
 100      1      1
  90      3      2
```